# How do I redefine a combobox's (linq-generated) datasource when replacing my dataset from xml?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a combobox for 'categories' which is bound to a table in my dataset. There is another combobox for 'subcategories' which is populated with a linq query to find the subcategories appropriate for the selected category in the first combobox, like so:

```
//get the category selected
            DataRow row = ((DataRowView)comboCategory.SelectedItem).Row;
            //query for appropriate subcategories
            EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query =
                from subcategory in flatRateData.Tables["Subcategories"].AsEnumerable()
                where subcategory.Field<Int32>("CategoryID") == Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"])
                select subcategory;

            DataView view = query.AsDataView();
            comboSubcategory.DataSource = view;
```

This is all fine and good and worked quite well when I had my program automatically load my dataset from an xml file upon starting up. However, when I tried to implement saving and loading datasets for the user, things went wrong. I load the new dataset like so:

```
comboSubcategory.DataSource = null;
flatRateData.Clear();
//read xml input into data
flatRateData.ReadXml(loadDataDialog.FileName);
```

But I get the following error and it highlights the "where" clause of my query:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.RowNotInTableException' in System.Data.dll
An exception of type 'System.Data.RowNotInTableException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
This row has been removed from a table and does not have any data.  BeginEdit() will allow creation of new data in this row.
```

If I don't allow the data source for the combo box to be set to begin with, it "works" but of course then the combobox is useless. I tried to set the combobox DataSource to null before clearing the dataset so that it wouldn't attempt to refresh the combobox's binding until the data has been replaced, but in fact it still runs into this problem even without the query code being executed. I'm assuming this means that the query and/or DataView I use are being kept regardless somehow, despite setting the DataSource to null.

This is my first question, so hopefully I have included the appropriate information! Thanks!

Comment: Did you reassign `query` after reloading the Dataset? Please expand your second code sample to show reassignment of the data source.

Comment: @TnTinMn `query` is local to where the combobox is populated (e.g. when selecting a new category, so new subcategories must be queried), so it is not accessible within the DataSet loading method. Should I try a query with broader scope?

Comment: So the query is performed in response to some selection changed event? is that correct?  If so, this may be due to change event firing in response to `flatRateData.Clear()`.  You may be able to prevent that by wrapping the dataset reload code with `flatRateData.BeginInit()` ... `flatRateData.EndInit()`.  I'm just guessing here as I still do not have a firm idea of the program flow.

Comment: @TnTinMn The query is performed in two places. Once in the form's constructor to populate it when the program runs, and once as you say in an event linked to the first combobox. Strangely, though, even when I disable the latter, I still get the same error from the one in the form's constructor. Just to verify, I did some debugging and it does not, of course, re-run the form's constructor when I load the new data. So even though the error is there, it doesn't seem to actually be executing that query to generate the error.